# Array of objects - correct way of updating an object within the Vue.js ecosystem

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm not sure exactly where the issue lies with this, but I'm going to see if anyone can help me understand what is going wrong with my code.

I am utilising the Vuex store, to keep a track of some state that is constantly mutating. I'm doing this as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    id: 0,
    contentBlocks: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      contentBlock.id = state.id
      state.contentBlocks.push(contentBlock)
      state.id += 1
    },
    updateContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      state.contentBlocks[contentBlock.id] = contentBlock
    },
    removeContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
      state.contentBlocks.splice(state.contentBlocks.indexOf(contentBlock), 1);
    }
  }
})
```

Creating and deleting blocks seems to work fine.

However, when updating a block - something is going wrong. The only way I can explain what is going wrong is by showing the log of the contentBlocks instance:

[image: console.log(this.contentBlocks)]

As you can see in the above screenshot, the object instances that has been updated (index 1 in the above example) is not quite correct, it doesn't seem to be an Observer object?

The failing line is:

```
state.contentBlocks[contentBlock.id] = contentBlock
```

So, I'm wondering...what should this be?

**Update**:

On the advise of the below answer I have the following:

```
updateContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
  const index = state.contentBlocks.findIndex(block => block.id === contentBlock.id)
  Vue.set(state.contentBlocks, index, contentBlock)
},
removeContentBlock(state, contentBlock) {
  const index = state.contentBlocks.findIndex(block => block.id === contentBlock.id)
  state.contentBlocks.splice(index, 1, contentBlock)
}
```

in my store. However, this isn't removing contentBlocks.

I've tried changing the suggested code to:

```
state.contentBlocks.splice(index, 1)
```

But this is causing some odd behaviour. For example, I have blocks of indices 0, 1 and 2 ... I mutate to remove index 0. All looks good - I have only the contentBlocks at indices 1 and 2 left. Yet they come with the content from 0 and 1 ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a limitation of Vue's reactivity regarding arrays.

[See #2 of Why isn’t the DOM updating?](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating)

> When you modify an Array by directly setting an index (e.g. `arr[0] = val`) or modifying its length property. Similarly, Vue.js cannot pickup these changes. Always modify arrays by using an Array instance method, or replacing it entirely. Vue provides a convenience method `arr.$set(index, value)` which is syntax sugar for `arr.splice(index, 1, value)`

You can solve this by using `Vue.set` or `Array.splice` in your module:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

// find the block's index in the array
const index = state.contentBlocks.findIndex(block => block.id === contentBlock.id)

// using Vue.set
Vue.set(state.contentBlocks, index, contentBlock)

// using Array.splice
state.contentBlocks.splice(index, 1, contentBlock)
```

Comment: I'm getting some really weird behaviour ... I'm not even sure how to explain it. I have three blocks, 0, 1, 2. I delete 0. Blocks 1 and 2 stay, but they contain the content values of 0 and 1 ???

Comment: And `state.contentBlocks.splice(index, 1, contentBlock)` doesn't seem to want to splice the contentBlock from the array...

Comment: The update worked - so this is the accepted answer as well.

Comment: @alexdykyi Please stop downvoting DigitalDrifters answer !! The method worked, and I’m storing an array of objects so I most certainly need an array!!